# AWS practices for computational offload (or other cloud services)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, scientific-computing

With AWS, at this moment, you pay for download (per GB) and usage (per hour) - with upload being free.

What are general practices of using AWS instances for just computational offload tasks (in scientific computing, for example)?

Can instance (programmatically) be turned on, data uploaded, computation job/task completed, return data retrieved, and finally performing a shut down of a system.

Since this would mean you would only pay for download plus usage cost for time it takes to perform: upload, computation, and download. I guess there would be little reason to pay per hour costs of idling system.

Comment: Have u explored EMR. EMR exactly does what you are expecting. The HDFS on EMR is extended to s3, you define a job which loads files from s3, executes the job(s)/task(s), pushes the content to s3 and then terminates the cluster.

Comment: Of course, machines can be launched programmatically, and an instance can stop or terminate itself, depending on its configured "shutdown behavior," and that of the attached storage ("delete on termination"), if any.  When the instance powers itself down (e.g. `sudo halt`) the infrastructure stops it, or terminates it entirely, as configured, stopping billing and optionally destroying it. And, you can bid on resources and wait for lower prices, using spot requests, if your work is chunkable (I made that up, can pick up where it left off.)  Not really sure what you're specifically asking, here.